# Printing on a bottle

Tags: print-design, print-production

I want to print CMYK digital label artwork onto a bottle that is concave vertically and convex laterally, is this possible and how?

Comment: So you're asking if such a shape is possible? I don't understand your question

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you talking about whether that shape exists? About how to print it? How to shape the artwork?

Comment: I don't think that is a question for Graphic Desing. Since you're asking for a Printing Technique

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's done everyday.

Odd shaped container surfaces can be usually accommodated by the screen printing process—as opposed to lithography, gravure, or letterpress which are suitable for flat substrate.

Many perfume, nail polish, and spice bottles are screen printed

In addition, various appliqués can be made and attached to the container.

Answer (score 1):

Pad printing can transfer ink to rounded surfaces - An entertaining explanation of the process is found after this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AX3fwGpT6Gs&list=PL16C0sYLJM1UXMLYkSl2Qk-r_yZht-JK-)

Comment: I've seen this operation. It's a kind of offset printing that is quite versatile for small irregular surfaces. Great suggestion.